# How to Sort my Map Arraylist Alphabetically

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist, hashmap, spinner

my items in spinner are not showing in alphabetical order on my app as it is written in my code, i want the KEYs to shows alphabetically exact way as i list them in my code.

see my code below

```
  spinner = (Spinner)  findViewById(R.id.spinner);

 final Map<String, String> flanguages = new HashMap<String, String>();
flanguages.put("Arabic", "ar");
flanguages.put("English", "en");
flanguages.put("French", "fr");
flanguages.put("Hausa", "ha");
flanguages.put("Igbo", "ig");
flanguages.put("Japanese", "ja");
flanguages.put("Yoruba", "yo");


 final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(flanguages.keySet());
```

this is ho it is showing on my app now
English
French
Arabic
Hausa
Japanese
gboYoruba

but i want it this way

Arabi
English
French
Hausa
Igbo
Japanese
Yoruba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code instead of

```java
 final Map<String, String> flanguages = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

use

```java
 final Map<String, String> flanguages = new TreeMap<String, String>();
```

Since HashMap will not store keys in order, it'll be used for lookup. Hence for storing keys in sort order better to go for TreeMap

Below is the full code just for reference

```java
final Map<String, String> flanguages = new TreeMap<String, String>();
flanguages.put("Arabic", "ar");
flanguages.put("English", "en");
flanguages.put("French", "fr");
flanguages.put("Hausa", "ha");
flanguages.put("Igbo", "ig");
flanguages.put("Japanese", "ja");
flanguages.put("Yoruba", "yo");


 final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(flanguages.keySet());
```